# DataTables + Bootstrap 3 enabling horizontal scrolling issue

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I'm having a problem with [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) integrated in [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/) and horizontal scrolling is enabled

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Drefj/)

DataTables Initalization

```
/* Data Table Initialization */
    var equipmentDataTable = $('#equipmentTable').dataTable({
                                    "aoColumnDefs": [{ "sClass": "text-center", "aTargets": [ 0,25 ] },
                                                     { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 25 ] }],
                                    "sScrollX": '100%'
                             });
```

I don't know why the header is not aligned with the body of the table. Thanks in advance

Comment: you didn't provide the fiddle

Comment: @dima sorry forgot to save the fiddle. I updated my post, please take a look at it.

Comment: jquery dataTables support one row of `th` in `thead` only. If you check the CSS it is obviously `.table` that makes problems - it has padding on `> thead > tbody > tr > th` but not on the `td`'s, and for some reason fixed widths is injected to the `th`'s. I would suggest you create your own `.table` class from scrath with this starting point -> http://jsfiddle.net/5KbLt/.

Comment: It is a risky mix :) A responsive table layout mixed with dataTables mixed with markup dataTables not is very happy with.

Comment: @davidkonrad I see. I try your suggestion

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue, but solved it in a different way.

I modified the sDom parameter to wrap the table in an extra div:

```
<i>
sDom: 'r<"H"lf><"datatable-scroll"t><"F"ip>',
I then applied the following styles to the .datatable-scroll class:

/**
 * Makes the table have horizontal scroll bar if its too wide for its container
 */
.datatable-scroll {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: visible;
}
</i>
```

source

Comment: check the fiddle now.